# Firebase push notification for android

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification

Is firebase can run without internet connection ? I want to use firebase in my local server (php) for push notification after db change to my android device with no internet connection, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use push notification from Firebase offline because the system is using Firebase server which is owned by Google.

The following image will tell you about it:

[image]

In the center is the FCM server owned by Google. All the push notification is sent by the FCM server where the command to send the push notification is from your server.